# Oneboxing does not work for simple.wikipedia.org

Tags: feature-request, chat, onebox

According to [the chat FAQ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#formatting) Wikipedia pages are among the links that will be oneboxed. I tried to onebox http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Question but it did not work. The progress meter flashed for some seconds and then the link was shown like a truncated inline link. Then I tried with http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Question_mark and it neither worked. Thus, it seems that oneboxing does not work for http://simple.wikipedia.org. Is this a bug?

Here is a screenshot showing what happened:

[image: Screenshot showing the problem]

And here is [the transcript](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3077/conversation/oneboxing-does-not-work-for-simple-wikipedia-org).

Comment: Boo! Discrimination of the simple-minded!

Comment: -1 should have phrased this Q in simple english

Comment: @BenBrocka What about "No box for simple"? Was that a reason for a real down-vote?

Comment: It's a joke, I didn't *actually* downvote