# Wikipedia oneboxing only works for languages with a two-letter code

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, onebox

While idly chatting over at [Software Recommendations](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12851/software-recommendations) (boring room name, I know. Anyone have any better ideas?), we noticed that [Simple Wikipedia](http://simple.wikipedia.org) articles (like [this one](http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer)) don't onebox. There [just shown as normal links](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/15103589#15103589), while [their en.wikipedia.org counterparts onebox](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/15103622#15103622).

After some more [investigation by Gilles](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/15103652#15103652), it looks like the system only takes two-letter language codes. This should be expanded to accept any language or flavor of Wikipedia.

Comment: [We aren't the first to notice this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129082/oneboxing-does-not-work-for-simple-wikipedia-org). I voted to close the earlier question as a duplicate because this one is a little more general (three-letter language codes are affected as well, not just `simple`).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have changed chat to accept up to 15-character subdomains for Wikipedias, and I've also added the dash. If I didn't miss any, `zh-classical` is the longest one, so this should catch [all of them](http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/List_of_Wikipedias).

[image: ONEBOX ALL THE WIKIS!]

Comment: Are you developing chat again? I've got a few feature-requests :P